# Firefox OS keyboard event

Tags: firefox-os, virtual-keyboard

Does anyone know if in Firefox OS, when keyboard opens, I have an event for that and if so, which is it?

I need to modify my screen on keyboard opening event. Viewport getting shrinked and I need to control the UI on this event.

Answer (score 2):

### Answers from dev-b2g@lists.mozilla.org

**@YuanXulei(袁徐磊)**

> Hi, There is no special event for keyboard opening, but the keyboard
> opens after receiving the focus event of current input field. So you
> may listen to that event instead.

**@Alive**

> There would be some timing difference (mainly from keyboard overlay
> transition) between 'focus' and 'resize' event. So 'resize' is the
> correctly event to go.
>
> The process is:
>
> -> User app focuses the input field
>
> -> Keyboard app gets focus event via Keyboard API
>
> -> Keyboard app updates its url with hash
>
> -> Keyboard manager in System app is notified via mozbrowserlocationchange event
>
> -> Keyboard manager performs the opening transition of keyboard overlay
>
> -> In the end of the opening transition, keyboard manager notifies window manager with 'keyboardshow' event
>
> -> Window Manager in System app invokes 'current' app's |appWindow.resize()| method.
>
> -> appWindow calculates the height and adjust the size of the container, the iframe in the container is then resized
>
> -> Use app gets resize event.

** Link to discussion **

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.b2g/fXfzRsuhWcI

Comment: If you are in for some basic UI changes, you might not even have to resort to JS/events for that, as some clever, well placed media queries and styles would do the job even - as the width/height changes after opening keyboard are reflected and can be queried in @media queries.

Comment: But media queries are not predictable on future releases of new devices.

Answer (score 0):

Since only certified apps have access to `mozKeyboard`, you probably can't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's currently an event for this, even for certified apps. The browser app uses a media query hack to detect when the `keyboard` is open which really isn't ideal. Feel free to [file a bug](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org) to add this feature.